# Linux tar: You may not specify more than one tar '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' option

Tags: software-installation, tar, error-handling, node.js

I am trying to install the latest Node on my Linux system by running the following terminal command, I keep getting the following error.
tar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or  '--test-label' option Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
This terminal command I copied right off a website.

```
tar -C /usr/local –strip-components 1 -xJf node-v12.13.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You command should be something like:

```
tar -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 -xJf node-v12.13.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

but to simplicity you can use:

```
cd /usr/local
tar --strip-components=1 -xJf /path/to/node-v12.13.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

Also check if you really need `--strip-components`

P.S. You may need syntax like this: `--strip-components 1`

Comment: You are correct that I don't need `--strip-components`. Once it installed I did a check to see if it took the installation by running `node -v`. It is still showing its previous version I installed. Do I need to restart the system?

Comment: @ThN, no, you do not need to restart.

Comment: Try to go to in to bin directory and execute it on this way: `./node -v`

Comment: This installation did not install in the folder /usr/bin. It is in /usr/local/bin. I was able to execute it, but only after I provided its exact location.

Comment: @ThN, correct. So you can start it from /usr/local

Comment: If you are right with that needed = , I would recommend to file a bug against the option parser.